# Object or array in twig file Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

i edited the post

where i set $appartement:

```
$appartement = new Apartement ();
$user=1;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$appartement = $em->getRepository('LeymaxDashboardBundle:Apartement')->find(1);
```

well i think that i have a syntax error that what i have in the controller that send s params to twig file :

```
return $this->render('LeymaxDashboardBundle:Default:client.html.twig', array('apart' => $appartement,
                                                                            'user' => $connected_user->getId(),
                                                                            ));
```

in the twig file i do the following :

```
{{ path('leymax_changemodules_showModal',{'iduser': user,'profil':'client','apart':apart}) }}
```

the generated route is like so :

```
leymax_changemodules_showModal:
pattern:  /changemodulesModal/{iduser}/{profil}/{apart}
defaults: { _controller: LeymaxDashboardBundle:Default:changeModulesModal }
```

the error message :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

what's wrong i'm doing ?

Comment: what about checking it yourself?

Comment: i'm in the helping-mood today, but you're right @WouterJ ... i probably shouldn't encourage people to ask more questions of this type by answering them :)

Comment: Please add the code where you set `$user` and `$apart` and the exception message + stacktrace ...

Answer (score 1):

You can access a (public) property or method of an object in twig using the `.` syntax.

As long as this method's return value or property is of type string/integer - the following will work:

```
{{ 
    path(
       'route_name',
       {
           'parameter':  object.property, 
           'parameter2': object.someMethod 
       }
   ) 
}}
```

You can further add a `_toString()` method to the object's class that will return a i.e. the id ...

```
class Object {

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
```

... and then pass the object directly:

```
{{ 
    path(
       'route_name',
       {
           'id':  object
       }
   ) 
}}
```

Comment: well i thank you but i think that's not the issue , i would like to pass the whole object in the path. but the response is : preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string object given

Comment: you can aswell pass the whole object as parameters. There is no need to `json_encode`. Twig creates an `Array` from that json syntax provided as the `path` methods 2nd argument and passes it to the `generateUrl` of the `@router`. Where are you stuck?

Comment: If `apart` is an object you either have to add a `__toString()` method or query the method / property i.e. `apart.name` that shall be passed to the route-generation method. All described in my answer.